# ul list not centering in screen

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I have been looking around online and can't see the reason why my list is not centering

this is the html

```
  <div id="footer" class="clear">   
            <ul id="nav2">
               <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
               <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tcstrathclyde?ref=ts&fref=ts"><img src="images/facebook.png" /></a></li>
               <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="copyright"> Copyright 2013 Teen Challenge Strathcylde. All rights reserved. Charity No: SC022209</div>
 </div><!--footer-->
```

and the css

```
#footer {
width: 960px; height: 100px;   margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer ul#nav2 {
list-style: none; margin: 18px auto;
}
#footer ul#nav2 li {
    float: left; padding: 0 0 0 30px; margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}

#footer ul#nav2 a img {position:relative; bottom:10px; }

        #footer ul#nav2 li:first child { background:none; } 

        #footer ul#nav2 li a {
            font-size: 30px; color: #222930; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; 
        }

            #footer ul#nav2 li a:hover, #header ul#nav1 li a:active {
                color: #e9e9e9;
            }
```

any help would be much appreciated thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by centering?  any example you can give us?

Comment: I want to centre the ul list on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
#footer {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer ul#nav2 {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer ul#nav2 li {
    display: inline-block;    
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 150px;
}
#footer ul#nav2 a img {
    position:relative;
    bottom:10px;
}
#footer ul#nav2 li:first child {
    background:none;
}
#footer ul#nav2 li a {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #222930;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul#nav2 li a:hover, #header ul#nav1 li a:active {
    color: #e9e9e9;
}
```

**[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TvtYn/2/)**